# Scala parsing a string into an associative array

Tags: scala

I have a string `{(2,15,6),(4,11,6),(4,12,34),(4,15,3),(7,15,3)}` that I need to parse into an associative array like `[[2,15,6],[4,11,6],[4,12,34],[4,15,3],[7,15,3]]`.  What is the best way in Scala to parse this text?

Comment: An associative array is a map.  Do you mean an array of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear because you ask for, as commented by @heenenee, a map, but show something that is nothing in scala.

A very dirty way to have a List or Array of Arrays, as you're showing, would be:

```
scala> val str: String= "{(2,15,6),(4,11,6),(4,12,34),(4,15,3),(7,15,3)}"

scala> str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").split("\\s+").drop(1).grouped(3).toList
res40: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(2, 15, 6), Array(4, 11, 6), Array(4, 12, 34), Array(4, 15, 3), Array(7, 15, 3))
```

(replace toList by toArray if you prefer an array...)